# How to define a model for dynamically created checkboxes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am creating a table of users where I want to add a checkbox on each row and a delete button. When I click the delete button, I want to delete all users who were selected.

Now I am creating these user entries from an API response which gives me say id, name and email.

So my view looks something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in MyCntrl.data.users track by $index">
     <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
     <td>{{user.name}}</td>
     <td>{{user.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

What I want in my controller is to have an object with id of all the users for whom the checkbox was clicked.

Even if I create an object and assign it as model for checkbox, how do I add a key as id in that object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.isSelected">`

And then just filter `MyCntrl.data.users` for those that have `isSelected === true`

Comment: Yeah, that was a silly question. I don't know why I was trying to create a new object to store it rather than just use the existing one. Thanks for quick help.

Answer (score 1):

Because of JavaScript dynamic typing nature, nothing stops you from adding a field named 'isSelected' (or alike) to your models. Then, you can add `ng-model="user.isSelected"` to your `checkbox` tag.
Then, on deletion, check which entries have `isSelected` set to true and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for how you can track all the selected users in an another array:

**Example:** [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/P3InnaQv2z4CeojXlusl?p=preview)

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in MyCntrl.data.users track by $index">
     <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="tempVar" ng-click="toggleSelection($index)"></td>
     <td>{{user.name}}</td>
     <td>{{user.email}}</td>
</tr>

<!-- AngularJS Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedUsers = []; // initially the selected users array is empty 
  $scope.toggleSelection = function(index){
    var positionInSelectedArray;
    var arr = $scope.MyCntrl.data.users;
    var tempUser = arr[index]; // refers to the selected user object in $scope.MyCntrl.data.users array (further, we'll call it "arr")


    var userAlreadySelected = $scope.selectedUsers.filter(function( obj ) {
      return obj.userId == tempUser.userId;
    })[0]; //checks whether the user is already selected or not (if selected, then returns the user object)
    if (angular.isUndefined(userAlreadySelected)) {
         $scope.selectedUsers.push(tempUser); //insert the object in array containing selected users
    }else{
        positionInSelectedArray = $scope.selectedUsers.indexOf(userAlreadySelected);
        $scope.selectedUsers.splice(positionInSelectedArray, 1); //removes the user object from array containing selected users
    }
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: Added plunker for this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/P3InnaQv2z4CeojXlusl?p=preview